# jquery convert html to string and to html

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<body>
 <div>
    <img id ="img1" src="http://aboveandbeyondkm.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Angry-Birds-HD-Wallpaper.png" style="width:100px; height:100px;"/>
 </div>
</body>
```

and the following javascript:

```
var array1 = [];
array1[0] = $('#img1');

var ndiv = "<div style='border: 2px solid red;'>" + array1[0] + "</div>";
$('body').append(ndiv);
```

This is a waterdown version of what I'm trying to achieve but that's the basis of what I'm having difficulties with.

When I append ndiv it doesn't append the image because it's an object. I tried jquery text(), html() and parseHTML methods with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I made a jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VttM4/1/)

Thanks

**Update**

I wanted to thank everyone for their prompt reply. Guffa answered the question correctly based on what I provided. But my code wasn't as simple as I presented it. Eman Z answer was the easiest to incorporate into the flow of my code. Wish I could choose two answers.

Here's an example of what I'm doing. Just to give a background. There's a forum that has something called topics. Each topic have a title, comments. views and thumbnails. Each topic can have several thumbnails. In order to see the thumbnails to get a preview of the topic one would have to do click on a button. So I wanted the thumbnails to show up automatically without clicking. So what I did was create a bookmarklet which has an iframe which loads the page that the thumbnails are in. I save all this info to an array. So the example you see in the jsfiddle may seem like I'm taking images and putting it into another array but I didn't want to write all the code to get the images so I chose to show it this way for simplicity.

[jsfiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/VttM4/5/)

Comment: $(ndiv).appendTo('body');

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried this and it didn't work. The issue is I need array1[0] to be converted to a string (<img id ="img1" src="http://aboveandbeyondkm.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Angry-Birds-HD-Wallpaper.png" style="width:100px; height:100px;"/>) and then append the string to the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the gist of what you're trying to achieve:

```
    var nDiv = jQuery('<div />').append($('#img1'));
    $('body').append(nDiv);
```

If you want to use the string method you can use:

```
    $('#img1')[0].outerHTML
```

This will give you the html string.

Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VttM4/3/

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made me to the minimum refactoring of my code. I used the outerHTML. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

$('#img1') is a selector, which can have many results. If you want to get the first element of the selector you can use $('#img1')[0]. Then depending on the type of the result you can get to value, text, attribute or whatever you want.

Comment: $('#img1') does not return array of.results. It returns 1 object because.it uses getElementById. No need to.use [0] to get the first element. Cuz it's already single.object.

Comment: @num8er true that $("#img1") Return one object, but this one object is a jQuery object that contains inside it one DOM object (html img element) and hence you have to index the JQuery object

Answer (score 0):

To do it like that you would need to turn the image element into an HTML string.

You can just create elements instead of creating HTML code for them first. This will move the image into the element:

```
var img = $('#img1');
var ndiv = $('<div>').css('border', '2px solid red').append(img);
$('body').append(ndiv);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VttM4/4/

If you want to copy the image element instead, you can use the `clone` method:

```
var img = $('#img1').clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(function (){
    var array1 = []; 
    array1[0] = $('#img1'); 
    var ndiv = "<div style='border: 2px solid red;'>" + array1[0].html() + "</div>";
    $(ndiv).appendTo('body');
});
</script>
```

Comment: The `html` method returns the HTML code inside the element, which is an empty string for an image element.

Comment: I think.problem.is.not.in.my code. It's because the.author.of.question does not handle.document.ready event.

Comment: Thank You Guffa I've fixed it in my next answer. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
array1[0] = $('#img1')[0]; 

var ndiv = "<div style='border: 2px solid red;'>" + array1[0] + "</div>";

$(ndiv).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was wrong in my previous answer. As said Guffa getting html() of image will return null.
So here is working solution:

```
<script> 
$(function (){ 
    var array1 = []; 
    array1[0] = $('#img1').clone();
   var $ndiv = $("<div style='border: 2px solid red;'></div>");
   array1[0].appendTo($ndiv);
   $ndiv.appendTo('body'); 
}); 
</script>
```

Thank You Guffa for Your comment.